# How to add a cookie or header in incoming http request in playframework java

Tags: playframework

I have created a action composition which intercepts incoming request and i need to add a cookie or header in the request. I am using *Play 2.4.6*

I have tried the following using action composition as interceptor below but it didn't work:

```java
Request request = ctx.current().request();

Map<String, String[]> headers = request.headers();
headers.put("COOKIE", new String[]{SSO_COOKIE+"="+SSOToken});
headers.put("COOKIE", new String[]{"abc"});
request.headers().put("yasir", new String[]{"xyz"});
request.headers().putIfAbsent("abc", new String[]{"tttt"});             
ctx.request().headers().put("abc11", new String[]{"tttt"}); }
```

Comment: if a request comes to you, you should handle it, and then return the response. why did you want to add a cookie to the request? you want to pass the request to another controller? I guess you may want to add the cookie to the response not the request, right?

Comment: @Yasir Can you show your action code? You are using scala or java?

Comment: so the reason why i want to do that is due to a bug where mobile client is not sending a particular security token as a cookie and the authentication module which is a legacy code and cannot be touched or updated at this moment on the server side expects that token in the cookie. The client can easily add the cookie but it will break the old clients running on previous versions when we move our new APIs in prod. So i created an interceptor (action composition) and tried adding headers but it has no effect.

Comment: I am going to add the code snippet in the question

Comment: Any idea guys. Do you need any more details.